# Autocorrelation function of random variable from Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-functions

I do a numerical experiment and find something strange.
Suppose I have a unit vector on a sphere $(m_1,m_2,m_3),(m_1^2+m_2^2+m_3^2=1)$, then I rotate the vector on the sphere according to the following rules:

1> I chose uniformly a vector from the unit sphere $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$;

2> I rotate the vector $(m_1,m_2,m_3)$ around the axis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ at a uniform speed and sample its value uniformly, for example, I sample its value every theta angle;

3> every time I sampled N samples(eg, $N=10$), I go back to step 1 and repeat.

After I get enough sample, I compute the auto-correlation function of $m_1,m_2,m_3$ separately. I find that they behave like this:[image]

Initially, I choose $(m_1,m_2,m_3)=(-1,-1,1)/\sqrt{3}$.

The peculiar points are:

1> Two of these functions collapse;

2>The don't go to zero but oscillate at a fixed amplitude as time $x$ goes to $\infty$.

3>They decay to the fixed amplitude at the time $x= N$($N$ is the number of samples I take everytime I choose a vector $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$).

Can someone give a explanation about what happens here?

Comment: The problem could be in the way you choose uniformly a vector from the unit sphere. How do you proceed ? A rather frequent **flawed** method is to select uniformly a longitude on $[0,2\pi]$ and a latitude on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ (in this case, the poles regions are over-representated)

Comment: Of course this is not a uniform distribution of unit sphere, since for each theta, the length of the circle is not the same. I use 3 gaussian distribution of average 0 and \sigma=1. But I don't think that is the key point.  After I tried more, I find that the number of samples N after choosing a random vector (v1,v2,v3) is important, I have to choose the N  carefully so that after N samples, I go back to the original position, otherwise, the curve won't be so smooth and so "sinus".